# Python 2.6, global variable wont change, calling functions in another function

Tags: python, function, global-variables, global, python-2.6

```
def coins():
    #randomly generated amount of coins, can throw them
    global num_coins
    print 'You have', num_coins, 'coins left.'
    opt = yon('You could throw a coin if you wanted too. Y/N')
    if opt == 'Y' and num_coins >0 :
        print 'You throw a coin. It clutters around the ground.'
        num_coins = int(num_coins)
        num_coins -= 1
        num_coins = str(num_coins)
        print 'You have', num_coins, 'coins left.'   
    else:
        'You decide to keep your change for later.'
    if num_coins == 1:
        inventory['coins'] = inventory['coin']
    if num_coins == 0:
        del inventory['coin']                               
    return num_coins
    return options()

amount = random.randrange(5, 12)
num_coins = str(amount)
inventory = ['Lighter', 'Phone', num_coins + ' Coins', 'Empty', 'Empty']
```

Hello all, making a text based game. and I am having a hell of a time trying to get my code to work. When I call the function coins(), and choose to throw a coin. It does not take away any coins from the global variable num_coins. I have a separate function that calls all the functions I have in my code as well, (options()). It also will not return me to the function options(). Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code, it is impossible to guess what the problem with `options` is...

Comment: Basically any time you assign to a global variable in a function, you're making a mistake. That's why python makes it quite hard to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to keep switching between `int` and `str`. You can use `str.format` to include the value in a string:

```
print "You have {0} coins left.".format(num_coins)
```

Instead of using a `global`, make `num_coins` an argument and `return` it afterwards:

```
def coins(num_coins):
    ... 
    return num_coins
```

Now when you call `coins`, do:

```
num_coins = coins(num_coins)
```

It is now much clearer what is happening.

Comment: the only problem with this, is that it goes through the function when the program starts. I am trying to get my program to assign a random number before i have to access the function. I decided to get rid of the random entirely. Basicly rewriting everything i posted. Still cannot get my function to call the function options()

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Please edit your question to provide the relevant information.